# How to create a message dialog or popup using devexpress xaf

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, devexpress, messagebox, xaf

How would I create or is there built in functionality in XAF to display a message box in a XAF web application?

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches.

You can use the [ConfirmationMessage](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xaf/DevExpressExpressAppActionsActionBase_ConfirmationMessagetopic) property of any action.

For more advanced scenarios, there is a sample project attached to [this support centre](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/S19008) ticket which demonstrates how to display a dialog via a `PopupWindowShowAction`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at "Actions" and "Pop-up Window". Check out:

> [Action that Displays a Pop-up Window](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument2723)

Answer (score 0):

The new XAF 17 has Toast Notification:

```
Application.ShowViewStrategy.ShowMessage(options);
```

In previous versions you can use JavaScript alert:

```
WebWindow.CurrentRequestWindow.RegisterClientScript("XafMessageBox", "alert('" + message + "');");
```

If you need to display a dialog with "OK"/"Cancel" or "Yes"/"No", use this object:

```
[NonPersistent]
public class ConfirmationPopup
{
    public ConfirmationPopup(string prompt)
    {
        Prompt = prompt;
    }

    public string Prompt { get; private set; }
}
```

And this code in View controller:

```
private void ShowConfirmationPopup(string prompt)
{
   var confirmationView = Application.CreateDetailView(Application.CreateObjectSpace(), new ConfirmationPopup(prompt), View);
   Application.ShowViewStrategy.ShowViewInPopupWindow(confirmationView, PopupConfirmed, PopupCancelled, okCaption, cancelCaption);
}

private void PopupCancelled()
        {
        }

    private void PopupConfirmed()
    {
    }
```